# Есть ли в Go тернарный оператор?

Tags: golang

Есть ли в Go тернарный оператор?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В go нет тернарного оператора. Вместо него нужно использовать условный оператор. То есть вместо

```
result = check ? true : false;
```

нужно писать

```
if check {
    result = true
} else {
    result = false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант сократить так

```
result = false
if check {
    result = true
}
```

Comment: Чем ваш вариант ответа отличается от ответа товарища @stanislav?

Comment: Ничем, просто вариант записи, если любите сокращать код и стремитесь к уменьшению строк, result изначально будет проинициализирован как false, и в гоу не надо назначать явно
var result bool // result уже false

Comment: Допустим, тогда зачем вы явно инициализируете в своем ответе?) Ваш пример ни чем не отличается от другого ответа, и количество кода одинаковое, разве что нет лишней конструкции, но это на "наведение марафета" не тянет, неа.

Comment: ну как же, красивее и всего 4 строки, да можно заменить на инициализацию

Answer (score 1):

В Go нет тернарного оператора. Вместо этого, вы можете использовать условную конструкцию `if`, чтобы выполнить различные действия в зависимости от условия. Например:

```
x := 10
y := 5
var max int
if x > y {
    max = x
} else {
    max = y
}
```

В этом примере переменная `max` будет равна 10, так как условие `x > y` истинно.

Также вы можете использовать укороченную форму условной конструкции `if`, чтобы не создавать отдельную переменную:

```
x := 10
y := 5
if max := x; x > y {
    // max доступна только внутри этой ветки
    fmt.Println(max) // 10
} else {
    // max доступна только внутри этой ветки
    fmt.Println(max) // 5
}
```

В Go есть также тип данных `switch`, который может быть использован для выполнения различных действий в зависимости от значения переменной.

Синтаксис условной конструкции `switch` выглядит следующим образом:

```
switch variable {
case value1:
    // действия, выполняемые при variable == value1
case value2:
    // действия, выполняемые при variable == value2
...
default:
    // действия, выполняемые при любом другом значении variable
}
```

Например:

```
x := 10
switch x {
case 5:
    fmt.Println("x равно 5")
case 10:
    fmt.Println("x равно 10")
default:
    fmt.Println("x не равно 5 или 10")
}
```

В этом примере будет выведено "x равно 10", так как значение переменной x равно 10.

В конструкции `switch` вы можете указать несколько значений для одного случая, разделив их запятыми:

```
x := 10
switch x {
case 5, 10:
    fmt.Println("x равно 5 или 10")
default:
    fmt.Println("x не равно 5 или 10")
}
```

В конструкции `switch` вы можете использовать условия в случаях, чтобы управлять выполнением кода в зависимости от более сложных условий. Например:

```
x := 10
y := 5
switch {
case x > y:
    fmt.Println("x больше y")
case x < y:
    fmt.Println("x меньше y")
default:
    fmt.Println("x равно y")
}
```

С помощью конструкции switch вы также можете использовать оператор `fallthrough`, чтобы выполнить код из следующего случая, даже если условие в текущем случае истинно. Например:

```
x := 10
switch x {
case 5:
    fmt.Println("x равно 5")
case 10:
    fmt.Println("x равно 10")
    fallthrough
case 15:
    fmt.Println("x равно 15")
default:
    fmt.Println("x не равно 5, 10 или 15")
}
```

В этом примере будут выведены следующие строки:

```
x равно 10
x равно 15
```

Оператор `fallthrough` позволяет выполнять код из следующего случая, независимо от того, истинно ли условие в текущем случае. Обычно он используется, когда условие в текущем случае проверяет несколько значений, а условие в следующем случае проверяет одно из этих значений. Например:

```
x := 10
switch x {
case 5, 10:
    fmt.Println("x равно 5 или 10")
    fallthrough
case 15:
    fmt.Println("x равно 15")
default:
    fmt.Println("x не равно 5, 10 или 15")
}
```

В этом примере будут выведены следующие строки:

```
x равно 5 или 10
x равно 15
```

Обратите внимание, что оператор `fallthrough` должен быть последним оператором в текущем случае.

Answer (score 1):

Надысь я написал для себя несколько утилит, которыми активно пользуюсь в своих проектах. Вдохновил меня язык Rust, поэтому модуль назван [`go-rusty`](https://github.com/pakuula/go-rusty). Помимо всего прочего там есть и реализация тернарного оператора как дженерик-функции

```go
func If[T any](cond bool, Then T, Else T) T { 
  if (cond) { return Then } else { return Else }
}
```

Использую для присваиваний в одну строку

```
prefix := expr.If(direction > 0, "buy", "sell")
```

вместо

```
var prefix string
if (direction > 0) {
    prefix = "buy"
} else {
    prefix = "sell"
}
```

Но знаете, что я вам скажу? Тернарный оператор, неявный проброс исключений вместо явной проверки `if err != nil { ... }` и прочие компактификаторы кода здорово сокращают количество нажатий на клавиши. Но текст становится плотнее, и, лично для меня, значительно сложнее для чтения.

Есть своя правда во всех этих бесконечных `if`. В программах на нормальном Го, без вот этих вот тернарных операторов и прочих ухищрений, строчки короткие, много пустоты благодаря `if`, и глаз легко бьёт программу на части и не нужно вчитываться, чтобы понять, что в функции происходит. В отличие от.

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг вам нужен именно оператор, а не управляющая конструкция, можно написать короткую фунцию:

```
func TerOp(condition bool, first, second interface{}) interface{} {
   if condition {
       return first
   }
   return second
}

// 1 попугай  2 попугая  38 попугаев
parrots := "попуга" + TerOp(qty<5, TerOp(qty<2, "й", "я"), "ев").(string)
```

**Изменено после комментария Pak Uula**

Comment: Ваш пример не компилируется - к строке нельзя прибавить `interface{}`. Нужно использовать дженерик: `func TerOp[T any](condition bool, first, second T) T { if condition { return first } else { return second } }`

Comment: Ох, спасибо, что заметили. Там надо добавить .(string)

Comment: В крайнем случае, можно явно указать тип вместо interface{}